# issue with deploying application on users' computers(reporting)

Tags: .net, sql-server, client

I created an application in Vb.Net 2012. Deployed to users computers. Everything seems to work perfectly fine until I've included a report viewer component in the application. When they try to run any kind of report they get the following error message.....

> Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms

With some research I found that I needed to install

```
MICROSOFT® REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME
```

However when I try to run this i get an error stating that

> ```
> Setup is missing an installation prerequestit for Microsoft System CLR Types For SQL SERVER
> ```

Why is this being an issue? I don't need SQL server. I query my data directly from SQL SERVER and store it in DataSets.

Comment: for my Report Viewer - I use ReportEmbeddedResource, and ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSource - don't know if this has anything to do with the issue. Maybe the fact that it's LocalReport vs ServerReport?

Comment: The correct answer to the question "Why is this being an issue?" is "Microsoft."  Sorry, but you'll need the correct version of the CLR types (including 32bit and 64bit), and should install them with administration privs.

Comment: Are you including the ReportViewer dll with your application?

Comment: @kidiskidvogingogin no dont think so is that what the plug in is for?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're deploying your application, but for my cases, I have had to include the Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms.dll (and maybe Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll) files in my application's directory. You should be able to right click on the ReportViewer reference -> Properties -> Copy Local = True.